# React Router issue: Navigation not working as expected in multi-component layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, layout, react-router-dom, component-based

I'm building a React application with React-Router, and I'm encountering a problem with route navigation. I have a multi-component layout where I've organized my components into different files. Here's a simplified structure of my code:

- `App.js`: Contains top-level routes.
- `Layout.js`: Represents the layout structure with a sidebar, top bar, content area, and footer.
- `MainArea.js`: Contains additional nested routes specific to the main content area.

The issue I'm facing is that when I navigate to certain routes, the navigation doesn't work as expected. For example, clicking a link to `"/profile"` in the main content area should display the user profile, but it doesn't.

Here's an example of my code structure:

App.js

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { LoginPage, SignUp, LayOut } from "../src/Shared/export";
import Layout from "./Layout";
import MainArea from "./MainArea";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<SignUp />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<LayOut />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Layout.js

```
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Topbar from "./TopBar";
import Main from "./Main";
import Footer from "./Footer";

function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="layout">
        <div className="tob-bar">
          <Topbar />
        </div>

        <div className="content">
          <Main />
        </div>

        <div className="side-bar">
          <Sidebar />
        </div>

        <div className="footer">
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Layout;
```

MainArea.js

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Content from "./Content";
import Profile from "./profile/userProfile";

function MainArea() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/profile" element={<Profile />} />
        <Route path="/content" element={<Content />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default MainArea;
```

What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it to ensure that route navigation works correctly within my multi-component layout?

The App renders a blank page with no errors.

Comment: The `MainArea` is renderd inside the `Layout > content`

Comment: Correct, it is rendered by the `Layout` component. `Content ` and `Profile` components are not provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Layout` is ultimately rendering content that results in rendering ***descendent*** routes then the parent route necessarily should append the wildcard `"*"` matcher, or splat, to its path. This is so descendent routes can also be matched and render their `element` content.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<SignUp />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
      <Route path="/home/*" element={<Layout />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}
```

You should note, however, that all descendent routes build their paths ***relative*** to their parent route, so `MainArea`'s routes will resolve to `"/home/profile"` and `"/home/content"`. You need to ensure that links to these routes resolve to the complete path.

```
<Route path="/home/*" element={<Layout />} />
```

```
function MainArea() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/profile" // <-- "/home/profile"
          element={<Profile />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/content" // <-- "/home/content"
          element={<Content />}
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

If the intent is for the routes `MainArea` is rendering to be "root-level" routes then I'd recommend converting `Layout` into an ***actual*** layout route component. It will render an `Outlet` component instead of `MainArea`, and the routes that `MainArea` was rendering as descendent routes should now be rendered as ***nested*** routes directly.

Example:

Layout.jsx

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";
import Topbar from "./TopBar";
import Main from "./Main";
import Footer from "./Footer";

function Layout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="layout">
        <div className="tob-bar">
          <Topbar />
        </div>

        <div className="content">
          <Outlet /> // <-- render Outlet for nested routes
        </div>

        <div className="side-bar">
          <Sidebar />
        </div>

        <div className="footer">
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

App.jsx

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<SignUp />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
      <Route element={<Layout />}>                     // <-- pathless
        <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} /> // <-- "/profile"
        <Route path="content" element={<Content />} /> // <-- "/content"
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  );
}
```